# Deploying multiple .Net Core sites on Ubuntu server using Nginx

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I followed these instructions to get one .Net Core website running on Ubuntu using Nginx:

https://blog.cinlogic.com/2017/05/10/deploying-an-asp-net-core-web-application-to-ubuntu/

I created the following file in sites-available for my website "mysite1" and it uses the default port 5000, but if I want to create another website "mysite2" how would I go about doing this?

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite1

server {
    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite1.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite1.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```